# How to update from TFS Scrum 2.0 from Preview 4 to final RTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, scrum

I have a TFS 2012 project that I built using VS2012 RC and the "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.0 - Preview 4" process template.

Today the RTM for both TFS and VS 2012 were released.  I upgraded both TFS 2012 and VS 2012 from RC to RTM without any issue.

As expected, if I were to create a new project today, I can see that the template is no longer in preview status, but has been finalized with the RTM.

1) What exactly changed between Preview 4 and the final version?  I can't find release notes anywhere.

2) How can I update my existing project from Preview 4 to the final version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We have not made a bunch of changes to the template - if any. Any change to the template is only minor bug fix level.

2) We don't have an way to upgrade your template from one version to another version. It is a request that we have heard before though and it is on our backlog.

Ewald Hofman

TFS Program Manager

Comment: Thanks, good to know!  I have seen a few blog posts about updating templates of an existing project, but they are mostly in the context of moving from the Agile templates to the Scrum templates, and there is considerable work involved.  One would hope that simply updating to an improved/bugfixed version of the same template would be a simpler process.

Comment: Could the work items be exported from a project with the RTM process template and then witimport into the preview 4?

Comment: You mean the work item *types*. And yes you can do that safely.